# Changing image domain / path in css for production?

Tags: css, dns

Currently, for things like background images, our css files have no domain specified.  This works both in our development and production environments.

```
background-image: url(/images/bg.png);
```

For performance reasons (cookie-less domain), we'd like to switch this:

```
background-image: url(http://staticimagedomain.com/images/bg.png);
```

Ideally, we don't hard code those, so our development environments can still pull locally.

Any thoughts on how to best achieve this?

Comment: are these static files or are you generating them with a server side scripting language ASP or PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest hosting the CSS files in the cookie-less domain as well, and not just the images. Then you would be able to use relative paths, which will work both in production and in any other environment.

If you deploy your CSS file to the cookie-less domain:

```
http://staticimagedomain.com/main.css
```

Then you can leave the relative URLs `/images/bg.png`, which will work fine from both environments.

CSS files don't need cookies anyway.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, the images would be relative to the domain of the css file, not the domain of the containing page . . .

Comment: Yes it works fine. Something curious: I was checking for some examples to back up my answer, and I checked the CSS of Stack Overflow, Amazon.com, Yahoo and You Tube, which all use cookie-less domains. All of them host the CSS file on the cookieless domain, but then they still use full absolute URLs to reference the images.

Comment: However I also found this as a further source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488369/serving-css-from-a-static-domain

Answer (score 0):

Entry in the hosts file to redirect `staticimagedomain.com` to `localhost` or wherever your test pages serve from?

Not a great solution, but quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other sensible answers: Sometimes is useful to have two stylesheets, one for production other for development, with just a few differences (eg: some background-colors) to help identify visually the instances and prevent confusions. Your build-deployment script (Ant) would take care of moving the css files when going to production.

If you are doing this (or think it would be good to do this), then your question has a trivial answer.